# Parsing using NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

I am being returned some XML from a web service. Basically, the xml looks like this:

```
<response>
    <data>
    More XML here but the it's escaped by XML entities
    </data>
</response>
```

so, as you can see, I have xml that is valid, but the stuff inside data tag is escaped with XML entities. what's the best (most efficient) way for me to feed this into the parser?

What I am doing right now is, when I get the data from web service, I convert it into NSString....then replace the "XML escaped entities" with real ones.....then convert it back into NSData...then feed it into the parser. This doesn't seem like a very good solution so I was wondering if there's a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Alright, here's the xml that I am getting:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><ActivityId CorrelationId="d39007b5-ee69-41c7-a61d-831b456f9ea3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">aa88d1cd-253c-48d1-abeb-62a880bea806</ActivityId></s:Header><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><LoginResponse xmlns="http://MSS"><LoginResult>&lt;LoginInformation&gt;&#xD;
  &lt;User&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;UserID&gt;612&lt;/UserID&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;UserName&gt;Demo User&lt;/UserName&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;Email&gt;mssdev@mss-mail.com&lt;/Email&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;CompanyID&gt;17034&lt;/CompanyID&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;CompanyName&gt;PlanET Demonstration Agency&lt;/CompanyName&gt;&#xD;
  &lt;/User&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/LoginInformation&gt;</LoginResult></LoginResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

As you can see, everything in  is escaped.

Comment: can you provide a better example?  Is it just that things in the data like &amp; is escaped or is there full xml tags that are escaped like &lt;elementName&gt; etc...

Comment: Updated my question. Please check it out. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's kind of horrifying. Why don't you just take the contents of that tag (e.g. the data with the entities) and just pass that through another NSXMLParser? The first parser will have decoded the entities, and the second parser will be presented with the decoded version of the contents of that tag.

Comment: sorry, i am  not sure what you mean. I am still guna have to convert the contents of data tag into NSString, unescape the entities, put it back into NSData, and then send it to the next parser. Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: You're misunderstanding. When you pass the data through NSXMLParser to begin with, depending on the semantics of the parser, it will either give you a single NSData for the entire text of the <LoginResult> tag, or it will give you a sequence of datas for the text and entities (I'm not really sure which). If the latter, you can compress them all into a single NSData. Either way, you'll end up with an NSData containing the contents of <LoginResult>, with all entities already unescaped. You can then pass this through another NSXMLParser to parse it.